# using two mpu6050 to get more accurate and precise angles

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, mpu6050, gyroscope, imu

i have been using this gyro for a while, now i am aware of all measures taken, to improve the outcome of this board.

my question is: would using two at the same time improve the results?

if yes how to use them both?

thanks in apporch

Comment: Using two IMU on same board might not give you that same result as IMU units data depends upon placement and orientation soldered. They are advised to be soldered at the center of your board, as two IMU  can't soldered at the center of same PCB in same orientation.

Comment: @vaibhav, yes got it. it is actually not a problem since the acceleration measured is the same on all the board  (law of physics). the only reason to put the imu in the center is to avoid noise out of vibrations.

Comment: Maybe you can account for the displacement from the center by calculation. But using 2 units will only reduce some of the electrical noise in the sensors. Often a big part of noise on the gyros data comes from vibrations in the device. Let's say you are building a robot. The motors will induce vibrations, when running. These can get caught up by the gyros, depending on the positions of gyro and motor and the form of the frame. What kind of device are you building?

Comment: would you mind chrisl of you put your comment as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Using a Kalman filter might help here.